# magento rest api not working

Tags: magento, oauth, magento-1.7

I have followed steps like the following.

**Step 1.**

```
localhost/magento/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=localhost/magento/oauth_admin.php
```

Then I am getting following response:

```
oauth_token=bspq6x1c46xdw29lzobj3de4e6qvlt4a&oauth_token_secret=y636yh3zih27dq27lyzukez06b3vb1sp&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

**Step 2.**

```
localhost/magento/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=bspq6x1c46xdw29lzobj3de4e6qvlt4a
```

Then I am getting following response:

```
oauth_token=t9pefrwylmg7webyepsqepotlhzbytkp&oauth_verifier=awpnxj6xng3ymu6v2v2ccnttg5mmijy1
```

**Step 3.**

```
localhost/magento/oauth/token?oauth_token=t9pefrwylmg7webyepsqepotlhzbytkp&oauth_token_secret=y636yh3zih27dq27lyzukez06b3vb1sp&oauth_verifier=awpnxj6xng3ymu6v2v2ccnttg5mmijy1
```

I can access the URL:

```
localhost/magento/api/rest/products?oauth_token=t9pefrwylmg7webyepsqepotlhzbytkp&oauth_token_secret=y636yh3zih27dq27lyzukez06b3vb1sp&oauth_verifier=awpnxj6xng3ymu6v2v2ccnttg5mmijy1
```

But I cannot access this URL:

```
localhost/magento/api/rest/customers?oauth_token=t9pefrwylmg7webyepsqepotlhzbytkp&oauth_token_secret=y636yh3zih27dq27lyzukez06b3vb1sp&oauth_verifier=awpnxj6xng3ymu6v2v2ccnttg5mmijy1
```

or this one:

```
localhost/magento/api/rest/customers?oauth_token=t9pefrwylmg7webyepsqepotlhzbytkp&oauth_token_secret=y636yh3zih27dq27lyzukez06b3vb1sp
```

Comment: have you set the correct resources in magento backend for that user ?

Comment: yes "Vdt" **i have set all permission,attribute and role to customer, guest and admin for get response from API**

Comment: can you provide the response you get ?